# How to find Maximum of average in group by clause in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have a query like this
`select avg(TotalSale) as value from Sales group by SalesPerson;`

which gives me the output as

```
value
50.0000
250.0000
62.5000
```

I want to just get the max out of the values. What should i do?

I tried
`select max(avg(TotalSale)) as value from Sales group by SalesPerson;` which is wrong.
`select avg(TotalSale) as value from Sales group by SalesPerson order by value desc limit 1;` which works partially.

What would be  better approach to do this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Hi @jarlh MySQL

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your query....

```
 select max(avgvalue)
    from 
    (
        select avg(totalsale) as avgvalue
        from sales
        group by salesperson
    )z
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `order by` and fetch one row:

```
select avg(TotalSale)
from Sales
group by SalesPerson
order by avg(TotalSale) desc
limit 1;
```

You can also get the SalePerson involved with this as well.

Comment: First line `select avg(TotalSale)`  , did you mean `select MAX(TotalSale)` ?

Comment: @Dev-vruper . . . No.  The OP wants the maximum of the averages.

Comment: yes ,OP just wants a MAX average value , but I think this query will return the average of the entire `Totalsale` column and not the MAX value . http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/feb7d6/1
Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it can be done in a single query .Try this :

```
SELECT 
    Max(Totalsale) as Value
FROM
    Sales
ORDER BY avg(Totalsale)
LIMIT 1;
```